# Getting weird text back with EditText.toString() method in Android project. Why?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, tostring

I appear to have a fundamental gap in my understanding of an EditText object.  I have an Activity+Layout with a single EditText object.  After I type a few characters into the EditText object and hit the Enter key, I retrieve the text in my onKey() listener.  When I use the toString() method to retrieve the text I get back a weird string like:

android.widget.EditText@43749ff0

Despite the fact the EditText.mText property does show the string I entered, "123" during my tests.  Why is toString() returning a different result and what appears to be some kind of "uninitalize" value?  How do I get the desired string currently in the mText property and what is that strange value?

-- roschler

Comment: When a toString() method prints out a fully qualified class name followed by an '@' symbol, followed by a hex string, it is using the default toString() method of the Object class, and therefore has not been overridden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling toString() on a View Object, which probably does not have a toString() defined.

I believe you want to call this:

editText.getText().toString()

Answer (score 8):

Passing glance at the API suggests you should use the `getText()` method. `toString()` is a general method that applies to `Object` and all its subclasses (i.e., everything that isn't a primitive, to my knowledge). It's often overridden to supply more useful strings, but by default, it reports something just like what you posted - a sparse description and the object's hashcode. To be clear, the [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) defines `toString()` as:

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't use the 'toString'-method on this, use 'getText().toString()' in stead.

Answer (score 3):

Try `EditText.getText().toString()`

Answer (score 2):

Take a moment to read the java API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29

> toString
>
> ```
> public String toString() Returns a string representation of the object.
> ```
>
> In general, the toString method
>   returns a string that "textually
>   represents" this object. The result
>   should be a concise but informative
>   representation that is easy for a
>   person to read. It is recommended that
>   all subclasses override this method.
>   The toString method for class Object
>   returns a string consisting of the
>   name of the class of which the object
>   is an instance, the at-sign character
>   `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal
>   representation of the hash code of the
>   object. In other words, this method
>   returns a string equal to the value
>   of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```
>
> Returns: a string representation of
>   the object.

Comment: I've found this to be an incredibly common mistake for people starting with Android, I know I've done it, but its quite forgivable. Looking at the text you quoted:

 `"It is recommended that all subclasses override this method."` Reading this could easily convince someone that they would get the text entered in the TextView by assuming it overrode this method.

Comment: @Dan Sure, but I posted this so next time he sees a text that resembles: PACKAGE.CLASS_NAME@VERY_LONG_HEX_NUMBER he will know that `toString()` was not overridden. Unfortunately, this is true for many classes and is not all that clear from the API docs.