# Android Development: Find/get recently used Apps

Tags: android, android-activity

I need a little bit help getting information about the last lets say 5 application that was opened/used.

```
ActivityManager m = (ActivityManager)this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

        RecentTaskInfo task = m.getRecentTasks(5,0).get(0);
```

Then i used:

```
String output  = "the last application you've executed is '"+task.id+"' and the PID is '"+task.toString()+"'";
```

But it didnt work out well. I think im on the right track with ActivityManager to track the latest app.

Thank you!

And ye i only need to get enough information so i can run them.

//Simon

Comment: Did you run any apps before running your application?  Nothing will show up after you reboot your Android device/emulator.

Comment: @user727278: "But it didnt work out well" -- that is a useless description. Please explain in detail what happened.

Comment: Well i did just get some weird text that does not make any sense to me.

Comment: @user I believe I know what's happening, but next time, post your error with the code. It helps understanding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RecentTaskInfo` does not override `toString()`. Try using  `task.ComponentName.toString();` or `task.description`

http://www.devdiv.com/android/docs/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RecentTaskInfo.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentName.html

For an explanation of the string you see, check my answer here: [Getting weird text back with EditText.toString() method in Android project. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750007/getting-weird-text-back-with-edittext-tostring-method-in-android-project-why/5750073#5750073)