# How to get App info from RecentTaskInfo?

Tags: android

Currently, I can only get the IDs of recent tasks, as below:

```
final List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, 1);
for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
{
     System.out.println(""+recentTasks.get(i).id);
}
```

But how to get other info? like package_name, main_activity and so on?

Also I found some IDs are `-1`. What does it mean? Can we get info of these tasks?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804391/android-development-find-get-recently-used-apps

Answer (score 2):

`-1` means the task is NOT currently running.

You can use `recentTaskInfo.baseIntent` to get the `Intent` that was used to launch the task, then e.g. get the package name using `intent. getComponent().getPackageName()`.

Answer (score 1):

here, I used this code for bring running app to foreground from background.
I hope this help you...

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
 {  
final ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
final List<RecentTaskInfo> recentTasks = activityManager.getRecentTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE, ActivityManager.RECENT_IGNORE_UNAVAILABLE);

RecentTaskInfo recentTaskInfo = null;

for (int i = 0; i < recentTasks.size(); i++) 
{
    if (recentTasks.get(i).baseIntent.getComponent().getPackageName().equals(packageName)) {
       recentTaskInfo = recentTasks.get(i);
       break;
    }
}

if(recentTaskInfo != null && recentTaskInfo.id > -1) {
    activityManager.moveTaskToFront(recentTaskInfo.persistentId, ActivityManager.MOVE_TASK_WITH_HOME);
    return;
}
}
```