# Sending SMS puts long unwanted header in front of message

Tags: android, sms

I'm sending an SMS programmatically using the default SMS app.  I use the following code which works, but leaves a long, unwanted initial header at the start of the SMS message:

> "android.widget.EditText(98b023VFED..CL. ......ID
>   0,356-611,534#7f0c00db app:id/..."   [Main sms message follows here.]

This header appears to be the `EditText` box id that the phone number was added into. I certainly don't want this header in the message when it gets sent out, but that's the way it's working now.  How can I get rid of this header?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) 
{
    String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(getApplicationContext()); 
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(String.valueOf(phoneNumber))));
    smsIntent.setType("text/plain");
    smsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message);

    if (defaultSmsPackageName != null)
    {
           smsIntent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
    }
        try {
            startActivity(smsIntent);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            String ex = e.toString();
        }
    }
else // For early versions, before KitKat
{
    Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
    smsIntent.putExtra("address",phoneNumber);
    smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body",message);
    startActivity(smsIntent);
}
```

Comment: Your problem lies in wherever you are getting `message` and `phoneNumber` from, not in the code that you presently have in your question. BTW, always log exceptions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting weird text back with EditText.toString() method in Android project. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750007/getting-weird-text-back-with-edittext-tostring-method-in-android-project-why)

Comment: You were right, CommonsWare.  I found an error in parsing one the the edittext inputs. Thanks.